# How can I authenticate with google inside of a firefox plugin

Tags: firefox, authentication, google-api, mozilla

I'd like to add a calendar entry from my Firefox plugin to the user's Google calendar (with their authorization, of course). Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to authenticate with Gapi within the context of the Firefox SDK.

I tried including the client.js from gapi directly as a module in my source, but this isn't effective, since it can't access the `window` object. My next attempt was something akin to what I do with jQuery - load it in a content script:

googleClient.js

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var self = require('sdk/self');

function initAuth() {
  var worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
    url: 'about:blank',
    contentScriptFile: [self.data.url('gapi.js'), self.data.url('authContentScript.js')]
  });
}

exports.initAuth = initAuth;
```

main.js:

```
var googleClient = require('./googleClient');
```

I get the following problem:

```
console.error: foxplugin: 
  Error opening input stream (invalid filename?)
```

In the ideal situation, it would open a new window in the browser that allows the user to login to Google (similar to what happens when one requests access to the oauth2 endpoint from within a "real" content script).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I've made an npm plugin for that. It's called [addon-google-oauth2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/addon-google-oauth2) and works for Google OAuth2 tested with AdSense API. It's really simple, it just calls REST APIs for OAuth2. Steps:

1. Create an OAuth2 client for native application. No web or Android, just native.
2. If your addon is using jpm ok, if it uses cfx, please migrate to jpm
3. Download and save the dependency with npm
   `npm install addon-google-oauth2 --save`
4. Follow the tutorial on the README.md file. It's easy, just two API calls

   - refreshToken(options,callback);
   - getToken();
5. Insert the HTML and JS file on your data/ directory